# Mandelbrot Numba/Numpy vectorization?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numba, fractals

I wrote an interactive mandelbrot renderer in Python using kivy where you can zoom with the mouse pointer and am trying to optimize it as best as I can. I currently use this implementation to render the set/zoom (this is a small snippet, just the two functions used to render it):

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np


@nb.njit(cache= True, parallel = True)
def mandelbrot(c_r, c_i,maxIt): #mandelbrot function
        z_r = 0 
        z_i = 0
        z_r2 = 0
        z_i2= 0
        for x in nb.prange(maxIt):
            z_i = 2 * z_r * z_i + c_i
            z_r = z_r2 - z_i2 + c_r
            z_r2 = z_r * z_r
            z_i2 = z_i * z_i
            if z_r2 + z_i2 > 4:
                return x
        return maxIt

@nb.njit(cache= True, parallel = True)
def DrawSet(W, H, xStart, xDist, yStart, yDist, maxIt):
        array = np.zeros((H, W, 3), dtype=np.uint8) #array that holds 'hsv' tuple for every pixel
        for x in nb.prange(0, W):
            c_r = (x/W)* xDist + xStart #some math to calculate real part
            for y in range (0, H):
                c_i = -((y/H) * yDist + yStart) #some more math to calculate imaginary part
                cIt = mandelbrot(c_r, c_i, maxIt) 
                color = int((255 * cIt) / maxIt)
                array[y,x] = (color, 255, 255) #adds hue value 
        return array #returns hsv array, gets later displayed using PIL
```

I currently get pretty good performance. It can render a 500x500 area where every point is bounded (so basically a black picture, the worst-case) in about **0.08 - 0.09 seconds**, with 300 iterations. I'm using Numba JIT along with the parallelized range function 'prange()', which helps quite a lot.

However, I've heard that vectorization is usually the fastest for rendering these kind of fractals. After a lot of research (I'm pretty new to vectorization), I managed to put this implementation together:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

def DrawSet(W, H, xStart, xEnd, yStart, yEnd, maxIt):

    array = np.zeros((H,W,3), dtype = np.uint8) # 3D array containing 'hsv' tuple (hue,saturation,value) of each pixel

    x = np.linspace(xStart, xEnd, W).reshape((1, W)) #scaling horizontal pixels to x-axis
    y = np.linspace(yStart, yEnd, H).reshape((H, 1)) #scaling vertical pixels to y-axis
    c = x + 1j * y #creating complex plane out of x axis (real) and y axis (imaginary)
    z = np.zeros(c.shape, dtype= np.complex128)
    div_time = np.zeros(z.shape, dtype= int)
    m = np.full(c.shape, True, dtype= bool)

    div_time = loop(z, c, div_time, m, maxIt)
    
    array[:,:,0] = (div_time/maxIt) * 255 -20 #adding 'hue' value
    array[:,:,1] = 255 #adding 'saturation' value
    array[:,:,2] = 255 #adding 'value'
    
    return array


@nb.vectorize(nb.int64[:,:](nb.complex128[:,:], nb.complex128[:,:], nb.int64[:,:], nb.boolean[:,:], nb.int64))
def loop(z, c, div_time, m, maxIt):

    for i in range(maxIt):
        z[m] = z[m]**2 + c[m]
        diverged = np.greater(np.abs(z), 2, out=np.full(c.shape, False), where=m)
        div_time[diverged] = i      
        m[np.abs(z) > 2] = False
    return div_time
```

Without, the @nb.vectorize decorator, it runs horribly slow. (4 seconds worst-case for 500x500, 300 It.). With the @nb.vectorize decorator, I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "MandelBrot.py", line 13, in <module>
     from test import DrawSet
   File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Code\Python\Mandelbrot-GUI\test.py", line 25, in <module>
     def loop(z, c, div_time, m, maxIt):
   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numba\np\ufunc\decorators.py", line 119, in wrap
     for sig in ftylist:
 TypeError: 'Signature' object is not iterable
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I defining all the numba signatures the correct way?
Would this vectorization method even top my current implementation?

I would be thankful for every advice! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is already vectorized!

The idea of vectorization is to create [universal functions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html) that operate elementwise on arrays. You only need to define what to do on a single element and the vectorization mechanism will allow your function to be called using arrays.

This function does the calculation for a single point c:

```
def mandelbrot_point(c, max_it):
    z = 0j
    for i in range(max_it):
        z = z**2 + c
        if abs(z) > 2:
            return i
    return 0
```

You can vectorize it using Numpy:

```
@np.vectorize
def mandelbrot_numpy(c, max_it):
    z = 0j
    for i in range(max_it):
        z = z**2 + c
        if abs(z) > 2:
            return i
    return 0
```

Or you can vectorize it using Numba. Notice that the function's signature describes what to do with a single point:

```
@nb.vectorize([nb.int64(nb.complex128, nb.int64)])
def mandelbrot_numba(c, max_it):
    z = 0j
    for i in range(max_it):
        z = z**2 + c
        if abs(z) > 2:
            return i
    return 0
```

Then you can call the vectorized functions using scalars or arrays of any number of dimensions:

```
>>> p = 0.4+0.4j
>>> mandelbrot_point(p, 99)
8
>>> mandelbrot_numpy(p, 99)
array(8)
>>> mandelbrot_numba(p, 99)
8

>>> x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 11)
>>> mandelbrot_numpy(x, 99)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 2, 1, 1, 1])
>>> mandelbrot_numba(x, 99)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 2, 1, 1, 1])

>>> x = np.atleast_2d(x)
>>> y = x.T
>>> c = x + 1j * y
>>> mandelbrot_numpy(c, 99)
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  2,  2,  3,  5, 17,  3,  1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  2,  6,  6,  0,  0,  8,  2,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  6,  2,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 0,  2,  6,  6,  0,  0,  8,  2,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  2,  2,  3,  5, 17,  3,  1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
>>> mandelbrot_numba(c, 99)
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  2,  2,  3,  5, 17,  3,  1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  2,  6,  6,  0,  0,  8,  2,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  6,  2,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 0,  2,  6,  6,  0,  0,  8,  2,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  2,  2,  3,  5, 17,  3,  1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Numpy's [vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) greatly simplifies your code, but as the docs say it is *provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop*.

According to my measurements, the Numpy-vectorized version is slightly faster than your original implementation, and the Numba-vectorized version is an order of magnitude faster.