# Unable to optimize Fractal code with Numba

Tags: python, math, numba, fractals

I am writing code to visualize Mandelbrot sets and other fractals. Below is a snippet of the code that is being run. The code runs perfectly fine as is, but I am trying to optimize it to make higher resolution images faster. I've tried using caching on `fractal()`, along with `@jit` and `@njit` from Numba. Caching resulted in a crash  (from memory overflow I'm assuming) and `@jit` just slows down the execution of my program by a factor of 6. I am also aware of the many mathematical ways there are of making my code run faster, as I've seen on the Wikipedia page, but I would like to see if I can get one of the above methods or some alternative to work.

For creating multiple images in a row (to make a zoom animation, like this one) I've implemented multiprocessing (which seems to run 9 processes at once) but I don't know how to implement the same in the creation of a single high resolution image.

Here is my code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import cmath
import math

# pick the fractal
def fractal(z,c):
# Mandelbrot
    if fractal_type == 0:
        return z**d + c
# Burning Ship
    if fractal_type == 1:
        return complex(abs(z.real), abs(z.imag))**d + c

#naive escape time algorithm
def naive_escape(arr):
    h = arr[0]
    w = arr[1]
    d = arr[2]
    zoom = pow(1.5, arr[3]) * pow(10,int(np.log10(h)))
    x_cen = arr[4]
    y_cen = arr[5]

    for i in range(w):
        sys.stdout.write("\r{0:03}%".format(np.round(i/w * 100, 4)))
        sys.stdout.flush()

        for j in range(h):
            it = 0
        #coordinates
            cx = i - int(w/2)
            cy = j - int(h/2)
        #scaling
            sx = (cx / (zoom)) + x_cen
            sy = (cy / (zoom)) - y_cen

            c = complex(sx,sy)
            z = complex(0.0,0.0)

            while ((z.real)**2 + (z.imag)**2 <= 2**d) and (it < max_it):
                z = fractal(z,c)
                it += 1

            img[j][i] = color_dict[it]

    sys.stdout.write("\n")

    name = "fractal"

    cv2.imwrite("{}.png".format(name), img)
    print("\n{} created!\n".format(name), fractal_type)
```

I should clarify that the reason the coloring function `naive_escape()` takes an array input is because of my implementation of multiprocessing. Since `map()` in multiprocessing only allows us to map the function with one input, I just pass an array with all my input values.

The code pasted above is a snippet from a much bigger file, so please excuse me for any syntax errors.

Any help in making my code faster would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66941893/2148416) on a similar topic may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66941893/2148416) deals specifically with vectorization, but some additional optimization can be done.

You can start with Numpy vectorization, convenient but not really fast:

```
@np.vectorize
def mandelbrot_numpy(c: complex, max_it: int) -> int:
    z = c
    for i in range(max_it):
        if abs(z) > 2:
            return i
        z = z**2 + c
    return 0
```

Or Numba vectorization, which improves speed by an order of magnitude:

```
@nb.vectorize([nb.u2(nb.c16, nb.i8)])
def mandelbrot_numba(c: complex, max_it: int) -> int:
    z = c
    for i in range(max_it):
        if abs(z) > 2:
            return i
        z = z**2 + c
    return 0
```

Then you can apply some of the usual optimizations:

```
@nb.vectorize([nb.u2(nb.c16, nb.u2)])
def mandelbrot_numba_opt(c: complex, max_it: int) -> int:
    x = cx = c.real
    y = cy = c.imag
    for i in range(max_it):
        x2 = x*x
        y2 = y*y
        if x2 + y2 > 4:
            return i
        y = (x+x)*y + cy
        x = x2 - y2 + cx
    return 0
```

And you can also parallelize it (by rows in this example):

```
@nb.njit([nb.u2[:,:](nb.c16[:,:], nb.u2)], parallel=True)
def mandelbrot_parallel(c: np.ndarray, max_it: int) -> np.ndarray:
    result = np.zeros_like(c, dtype=nb.u2)
    for row in nb.prange(len(c)):
        result[row] = mandelbrot_numba_opt(c[row], max_it)
    return result
```

Some timings on a 1000x1000 array:

```
N = 1000
x = np.linspace(-2, 2, N).reshape((1, -1))
y = x.T
c = x + 1j * y

%timeit mandelbrot_numpy(c, 99)
1.59 s ± 40.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit mandelbrot_numba(c, 99)
100 ms ± 406 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit mandelbrot_numba_opt(c, 99)
35 ms ± 140 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit mandelbrot_parallel(c, 99)
10.9 ms ± 64.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: I am pretty new to Numba optimization, so I was only able to implement upto the the numba vectorization. Doing so reduced my times by a factor of 4. However, I want ```mandelbrot_numba()``` to return both the iteration count as well as the magnitude (for a different fractal implementation im working on). So I tried changing ```@nb.vectorize([nb.u2(nb.c16, nb.u2)]) -> int``` with ```@nb.vectorize([nb.u2(nb.c16, nb.u2)]) -> (int, float)``` and changing ```return i```  to ```return i, abs(z) ``` but it doesn't work. Any ideas on how to get multiple output from this?

Comment: You can return a tuple changing the decorator to `@nb.njit([nb.types.Tuple((nb.u2, nb.f8))(nb.c16, nb.i8)])`. But then the function can't be vectorized using `numba.vectorize`.

You may try to vectorize it using `numba.guvectorize` but this might be harder.

In any case, `abs(z)` will always be slightly above the divergence threshold (2 in the code), so I don't see the point in returning the magnitude.

Comment: it was to implement a smooth coloring method, which I found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plotting_algorithms_for_the_Mandelbrot_set#Continuous_(smooth)_coloring). Earlier, I had made a copy of the original `mandelbrot_numba` function, which returned the magnitude instead of the iteration count. On my laptop that took 1.4 seconds to make an image. With the optimization you suggested, it takes 1.2 second, which is better, but it still pales in comparison to 0.4 second which is when I run it as is. I want to make bigger images, so any ideas on how to make it faster?