# How to parallelise using Jit (Numba) parallel?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, jit, numba

I wanted to share with you how I solved my parallelisation problem I had with jit. Initially I had the code bellow and got this error:

**Code:**

```
@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def mandelbrot_2(cArray, iterations):
    count = 0
    for c in cArray:
        z = 0
        for n in range(iterations):
            z = np.square(z) + c
            if np.abs(z) > 2 : 
                count += 1 ; 
                break
    return cArray.shape[0] - count
```

**Error:**

```
/Users/alexander/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/typed_passes.py:326: NumbaPerformanceWarning: [1m
The keyword argument 'parallel=True' was specified but no transformation for parallel execution was possible.

To find out why, try turning on parallel diagnostics, see https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/parallel.html#diagnostics for help.
[1m
File "<ipython-input-56-9fcfc0a9fe03>", line 17:[0m
[1m@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
[1mdef mandelbrot_2(cArray, iterations):
[0m[1m^[0m[0m
[0m
  warnings.warn(errors.NumbaPerformanceWarning(msg,
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505968/2148416) illustrates how you can apply Numpy vectorization, Numba vectorization, or Numba parallelization in your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Import prange:
   `from numba import jit, prange`
2. **New Code:**

- Convert the first loop to indexing an array instead of using a new array element each time.
- converted the `range` in both loops to `prange` which I imported from Numba.

```
@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def mandelbrot_2(cArray, iterations):
    count = 0
    for c in prange(cArray.shape[0]):
        z = 0
        for n in prange(iterations):
            z = np.square(z) + cArray[c]
            if np.abs(z) > 2 : count += 1 ; break
    return cArray.shape[0] - count
```

Comment: It's not possible to run the inner loop in parallel because each iteration depends on the previous value of `z` and updates it.